# UIView doesn't seem to be remembering its tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I'm using CPPicker to implement a horizontal picker in my application, and I'm using tags to figure out which of my two pickers I'm talking about.

```
     // Picker creation
     CPPickerView *pickerView = [[CPPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 5, 150, 40)];
     pickerView.dataSource = self;
     pickerView.delegate = self;
     pickerView.peekInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 40, 0, 40);
     [pickerView reloadData];
     pickerView.showGlass = YES;
     [cell addSubview:pickerView];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        pickerView.tag = 0;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        pickerView.tag = 1;
    }

    return cell;
```

Then later, I check the tag to specify the title for the pickerView. But it only ever reads 0 for the tag, so both pickers have the same value.

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(CPPickerView *)pickerView titleForItem:(NSInteger)item {
    NSString *title = nil;

    if (pickerView.tag == 0) {
        title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (200 + (item * 20))];
    }
    else if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
        title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", item + 1];
    }

    return title;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't you think it'd be better to remove gratuitous anatomical references from your code snippet?

Comment: I would recommend putting a breakpoint on the line that says "pickerView.tag = 1;" to see if it is ever called. If it is not, then are you queueing and dequeuing your table cells correctly (I assume this is in a table view because you are using 'indexPath.section'.

Comment: It is being called, and it is a tableView.

Comment: One problem is that you are apparently adding `pickerView` as a subview of the cell, rather than as a subview of `cell.contentView`.  I don't know if that's causing your problem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Are you declaring picker view in a method or function. This would mean that it's not visible in another method or function.  You might need to make it a property or at least declare it in you class extension as an instance variable.*

The default value of a tag is zero, it might be better to start the tag count at 1, *then you will be able to tell if it's getting set elsewhere or not getting set correctly.*

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    pickerView.tag = 1;
}
else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    pickerView.tag = 2;
}
```

Comment: If I do this, the title doesn't get set at all. I guess the tag doesn't get set correctly, as its tag seems to be forgotten by the time it gets checked to set the title.

Comment: So there you go, issue is not where you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the tag to the pickerView, after you add it to the view.  The pickerView on the view is now a copy of the original instance.  Move the tag code above the addSubView call

Comment: This didn't do anything. (It was still referencing the one that was added to the view anyway.)